# Firebase descending order, prevent users changing negative timestamp priority

Tags: javascript, firebase

I currently have the following push:

```
ref.child("/chatboxes/{{ chatbox.pk }}/messages/").push({user_id:user_id, message:message, timestamp: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP});
```

I want to order on descending order so new messages are retrieved last. I read about this on SO and there were answers saying to just use a negative timestamp as priority. How do I prevent users from changing this timestamp client side so they can't mess with the priority?

Comment: Why would users change server timestamp? They can only affect local timestamp.

Comment: Sorry I meant client side. I can't check if the timestamp/priority (negative) is right in the firebase security/rules (only positive timestamp with 'now').